# Postgres grouping sets - Show count zero or named groups

Tags: postgresql, grouping, grouping-sets

I have the following query:

```
select count(*)
from "my_table"
where field1 = true and field2 = 'delivered'
group by grouping sets((field3), (field4), (field5))
having field3 = true or field4 = true or field5
```

For each group in the grouping set, I want to get the count of the true values. The problem with this query however is that it has no labels attach to it. In case there are no results for a group, the group is excluded in the end result. Is it possible to include groups with count 0 or create a set of labels so that it becomes clear to which group the count corresponds in the result?

Current result:

```
count
_____
1
2
```

Where field5 doesn't have any results so it isn't included.

Desired result:

```
count
-----
1
2
0
```

Or:

```
count_field3 | count_field4 | count_field5
------------------------------------------
1            | 2            | 0
```

Comment: please add sample dataset and expected result set

Comment: @VenkataramanR If added two possibilities for desired results. I already to work with the coalesce operator but gave exactly the same result.

Comment: I think you are filtering the results in the HAVING clause. Ideally, you should be getting field5 also in the resultset. your query is not complete.